# How can I keep the query string in address bar while avoiding redirecting on form submission?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, routes, react-router

I am trying to use the Spotify Web Api in a MERN application using [this package](https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node).

When the user enters an artist in the search form, I'd like to make a get request with the search value in the query string to use in my Express route handling.

The way I have it set up currently is working as expected, except for the fact that I'd like the query string to be in the address bar. With preventDefault() in the handleSubmit() method it does not get added.

When I remove preventDefault() the query string is present, but only after redirecting, so I cannot save the response in state.

Is there a way to fix this?  Or a better way to accomplish this?

Search component:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Search extends React.Component {

    state = {}

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: `http://localhost:8000/spotify/search?artist=${this.state['artist']}`,
          }).then(res => this.setState({ searchData: res.data }));
    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={(event) => this.handleSubmit(event)}>
            <input name={"artist"} value={this.state['artist']} onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}></input>
            <button>Submit</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

export default Search;
```

Express route handler

```
router.get('/search', (req,res) => {
    spotifyApi.searchArtists(req.query["artist"]).then(function(data) {
        res.send(data.body);
      }, function(err) {
        console.error(err);
      });
})
```

App.js Router

```
        <Router>
          <Switch>
              <Route path="/spotify/user" component={User} />
              <Route path="/spotify/search" component={Search} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
```

Comment: Just do a history.push to a route that looks like "/spotify/search/:keyword". In your Search component, you can check if a keyword exists and then show those results. If no keyword exists, you can show something else (such as everything). It'll show up as spotify/search/search%20term in the browser's address bar.

Comment: This is working for me. Thank you